# Error in admin.php or system/index.php when trying to upgrade to 5.4.0

Tags: error, upgrade, ee5, update

I know I submit a lot of questions that are likely basic. I still haven't solved the last one that was asked.

I noticed that the "5.3.2" in the bottom of my control panel was now yellow, indicating an update. I was expecting it to be a simple update, but it instead provided the following error:

> It looks like your ExpressionEngine installation is using an out-of-date /admin.php or /system/index.php file.
> Please make sure you have the latest version of each file in place and then try upgrading again.

I did a Google and [found this page regarding the same issue](https://expressionengine.com/forums/topic/252115/sanity-check-for-one-click-updater-when-admin-system-have-been-renamed) from a year ago (and version 4). Unfortunately, when examining my admin.php and system/index.php files and comparing to what he linked in the GitHub, it looks like I have the same file. I followed the manual update instructions when going all the way from 2 to 3 to 4 to 5, but it definitely felt like there were some holes in the process that EllisLabs themselves haven't addressed. Any advice or answers?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell from your question what actually is going on, but here is a suggestion for a way forward:

- [Download a clean copy of EE 5.4](https://expressionengine.com/?ACT=243)
- Create a clean / new install of EE 5.4 on some test system
- Copy the system / index files created in the new install
- Update the copied system / index files with relevant information from your existing system / index files
- Replace the system / index files on your 5.3.2 installation with the ones you've just created
- Try running the one-click updater again...

HTH

Comment: Thank you! The differences were very minor (looked like just two lines of code), but that allowed me to upgrade to 5.4.0. Thank you very much for your assistance.